# is there a way to solve this autoloader function problem in php?

Tags: php, spl-autoload-register

I have uploaded this code on online hosting. I am facing this autoloader function problem.
I have posted all my code and output below. Please check it and help me.

This is my database connection file.
db.php

```
<?php
class Db {
    private $host = "localhost";
    private $user = "guru77";
    private $pwd  = "123456";
    private $dbName = "testingProjects";
protected function connect(){
    $dsn = 'mysql:host='.$this->host.';dbname='.$this->dbName;
    $pdo = new PDO($dsn,$this->user,$this->pwd);
    $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE,PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    return $pdo;
}

}
```

This is my autoloader file

```
<?php


spl_autoload_register('myAutoLoader');
function myAutoLoader($className){
$extension = ".php";
$fullPath = $className . $extension;
include_once $fullPath;
}
 ?>
```

This is my index page 
index.php

```
    <?php
require_once('autoloader.php');

  $obj = new Post_view();
  $rows = $obj->show();

?>

<html>
    <head>

    </head>
    <body>
        <?php foreach($rows as $row){

        echo $row['title'];

        }?>
    </body>
</html>
```

post_view.php

```
    <?php
require_once('post.php');
class Post_view extends Post{

    public function show(){
        $results = $this->showAll();
        return $results;
    }
}


?>
```

post.php

```
  <?php
include_once('db.php');
class Post extends Db{

    protected function  showAll(){
            $sql    = "SELECT * FROM posts";
            $stmt   = $this->connect()->query($sql);            
            $results = $stmt->fetchAll();
            return $results;
        }
}


?>
```

Here this is my error_log file. this is the error that I am getting. I know there is something problem with my autoload function but I am not figuring it out.
error_log

[image]

Output
[image]

Comment: : "It looks like you're writing your own ORM. Have you considered using one that's already written, tested, and widely supported like [RedBeanPHP](https://redbeanphp.com/), [Doctrine](http://www.doctrine-project.org/), [Propel](http://propelorm.org/) or
[Eloquent](https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent)?"

Comment: is there anyway this error get solved?

Comment:  Please post code, errors, sample data or textual output here as plain-text, not as images that can be hard to read, can’t be copy-pasted to help test code or use in answers, and are barrier to those who depend on screen readers. You can edit your question to add the code in the body of your question. For easy formatting use the `{}` button to mark blocks of code, or indent with four spaces for the same effect. The contents of a **screenshot can’t be searched, run as code, or copied and edited to create a solution.** A screenshot of a generic 500 error is just taking up space.

Comment: This error is a standard "file not found" one. Check that path. Correct if necessary. Are you sure your autoloader is called `autoloader.php`? You don't specify in your question, but you do presume when you `require_once` it.

Comment: I already posted all the code above.I just put images for the output and log file

Comment: Please find all the code above

Comment: Don't use image for textual data, and especially don't show an image of something super generic. Consider: What are we supposed to divine from that screenshot? It doesn't help us. The error text, on the other hand, is helpful, but I couldn't see it since it's super tiny and hidden.

Comment: You can click on the image to make it large. I have added all the code. but else I can add it here?

Comment: Read my earlier comment about that image. Please don't post as images in the first place. They're inconvenient and inaccessible for some people.

Comment: I haven't used PHP in a long time, but don't you have to define your autoload function _before_ you call `spl_autoload_register()`? I think your call to register the autoloader might be failing, but you don't check the return value of `spl_autoload_register()` so you don't know if it succeeded or not.

Answer (score 1):

Your autoloader is trying to look up the classname Post_view (with a capital P), so it's generating the path 'Post_view.php', with a capital P. But the actual paths are case-sensitive, even though many things in PHP are not.

I would recommend changing your filename and classname to match, either making it Post_view.php (capital P) or changing the class (and all references, it's the references that matter in this case) to be post_view (lowercase P). That should resolve it.

You could also do things like changing your autoloader to force everything to lowercase but the filename and class and all references should have their casing match IMO as a best practice (even though PHP classnames aren't case sensitive).